# How close to uniform are Perron-Frobenius eigenvectors?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, eigenvector

Let $A=(a_{i,j})$ be a square matrix with non-negative entries. (Assume $A$ is symmetric, if it helps.) Let $v$ be a Perron-Frobenius eigenvector. What do we need to assume about $A$ in order to have useful bounds on how "flat", or close to uniform, $v$ is?

One easy bound (for $v$ having strictly positive entries, as is implied by standard conditions) is given by
$$\frac{\max_i v_i}{\min_i v_i} \leq \frac{|A|}{\min_i \sum_j a_{i,j}} \leq \frac{\max_i \sum_j a_{i,j}}{\min_i \sum_j a_{i,j}}.$$
EDIT: Actually, I no longer remember quite how I proved this "easy bound", which may not even be true.

Comment: What do you mean by "useful bounds", and why is the "easy bound" not useful?

Comment: Oh, it *can* be useful, but I was assuming people would have a battery of results better than something I thought of in the shower.

Comment: (1) I think $A$ symmetric is necessary - i.e. it does help. Take a path, so the adjacency matrix has nonzero entries only on the diagonal, just above, and just below, and multiply all the entries just above the diagonal by $2$ and just below the diagonal by $1/2$. We have now multiplied the ratio between the first and last entry by $2^{n-1}$. (2) what is $|A|$ in the displayed equation?

Comment: The operator norm. But don't trust that bound! A friend tekks me he just found a counterexample (not symmetric I think). My "proof" in the shower was most likely wrong (but then I may have forgotten a crucial detail).

Comment: I believe the adjacency matrix of a depth $n$ binary tree gives a symmetric counterexample, as $\max_i v_i / \min_i v_i$ should be close to $\sqrt{2}^n$ but the row sums are bounded between $1$ and $3$.

Comment: @WillSawin : Can you elaborate on your comment, especially on $\approx\sqrt 2^n$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Sure, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on my comment, at Iosif Pinelis's request.

The claimed bound is not right, even for symmetric matrices.

Let $G$ be a binary tree of depth $n$ - i.e. $2^n$ leaf nodes, connected in pairs to $2^{n-1}$ nodes one level up, and one root node on the $n$th level. Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$. The row sums of $A$ are all $1$, $2$, or $3$, so the right side of the bound is at most $3$.

Let's calculate the Perron-Frobenius eigenvector.

The Perron-Frobenius eigenvector takes the same value, say $1$, on the leaf nodes. For eigenvalue $\lambda$, it must take the value $\lambda$ on nodes one level up from the leaves, then $\lambda^2-2 $ on the next level, and so on.

If $V_i$ is the value on the $i$'th level up from the leaves then the eigenvector condition gives the recurrence relation $ \lambda V_i =2 V_{i-1} + V_{i+1}$, which gives $$V_i = \sqrt{2}^i U_i (\lambda/ 2\sqrt{2})$$ where $U_i$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind.

The equation is satisfied at the $n$th node if $V_{n+1}=0$, i.e. if $\lambda /2\sqrt{2}$ is equal to a root of the Chebyshev polynomial. The largest eigenvalue comes from the largest root, which is $\cos (\pi / (n+2))$, so $\lambda =2 \sqrt{2} \cos (\pi / (n+2))$, and the value at the root is given by $$\sqrt{2}^n U_n ( \cos(\pi/(n+2)) = \sqrt{2}^n \sin ( (n+1) \pi / (n+2)) / \sin ( \pi / (n+2) ) = \sqrt{2}^n .$$

So the left side can grow arbitrarily large with the right side bounded.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Probably I am missing something here. I think the general solution of your recurrence relation is of the form $c_1a_1^i+c_2a_2^i$ (unless $\lambda=2\sqrt2$). Why then a polynomial?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Well, the expression you give is certainly a polynomial function in $a_1$ and $a_2$. And $a_1$ and $a_2$ are polynomials in $\lambda$ and $\sqrt{\lambda^2-8}$. So the whole thing ends up a polynomial in $\lambda$ after some Galois-invariance removes the $\sqrt{\lambda^2-8}$ term.

Comment: Thank you for your further response.

Comment: Thanks. Trivial remark: "and the value at the leaf is given by" should be "and the value at the root is given by".

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a simple graph, then the quantity $\max_{i,j} v_j/v_i$ is sometimes called the "principal ratio", and is [maximized by a kite graph](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3799478). The bibliography of this linked paper of Tait and Tobin might be of interest.

I did a short mathscinet binge starting from Tait and Tobin and found the following results for more general non-negative matrices:

- Minc, Henryk: [On the maximal eigenvector of a positive matrix.](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=266414)
- Ostrowski, A. M: [On the eigenvector belonging to the maximal root of a non-negative matrix](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=137718).
- Hartfiel, D. J: [Bounds for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a nonnegative matrix which involve a measure of irreducibility](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=325648).
- Latham, Geoff A: [A remark on Minc's maximal eigenvector bound for positive matrices](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1311434).

Perhaps one of them suffices for your application? All of these bound the principal ratio of $A$ in terms of its entries; similar in spirit to the "easy bound" in the question.